# Does objective-c follow the order of operations (Bedmas)?

Tags: objective-c, excel, equation

I'm just wondering, because the app I built does a pretty long equation, and the result is a different than when it's done on an Excel spreadsheet, where I got the equation. The difference gets higher the higher the input numbers are. Here is the equation that I entered in xcode:
`360 * num1 * num3 * (1 - powf(14.9 / num1, 0.286))`
(num1 and num3 are the input numbers).
Here is the Excel calculation:
`=360*R9*R11*(1-((R10/R9)^0.286))`
(`R9` is equal to `num1`, and `R11` is equal to `num3` and `R10` is 14.9)

I don't see a difference in the equations, but if you do, please point it out. My quess it one of the two (probably the ob-c one) is doing something different than what I expected.

Comment: @H2CO3 Because someone used Excel to plan/balance/test that formula? For example, some game designers do that to balance out stats for in-game entities.

Comment: Brackets, **Exponentiation**, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction.

Comment: You should check that cells R9 R10 and R11 actually contain the numbers that you think they do - if you enter the numbers you think the cells contain then you will get the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Objective-C is a superset of C.

So all the features that C has, Objective-C has as well.

```
 360 * num1 * num3 * (1 - powf(14.9 / num1, 0.286)) (num1 and num3 are the input numbers)
          A * num3 * (1 - powf(14.9 / num1, 0.286)) 
                 B * (1 - powf(14.9 / num1, 0.286)) 
                 B * (1 - powf(C, 0.286)) 
                 B * (1 - D) 
                 B * (E) 
                      F
```

And just for information, BEDMAS is not fully followed. If D & M are there at same level, the left most will be evaluated first, and so is the rule for A & S. However this does not look big deal, but when it comes to truncation and rounding with decimal numbers it creates a big problem.

```
a * b / c is calculated  as "(a*b) / c"
```

whereas

```
a / b * c is calculated as "(a/b) * c"
```

Comment: So any idea why the answer would be different?

Comment: If num1 is 300 and num3 is 1, xcode gives me 62239, and xcel gives me 62205

Comment: @user1930931 1. It's not Xcode that calculates that, it's the math functions of the C library. 2. Floating point numbers are not exact, a small difference can occur, especially if you're using functions like `exp()`.

Comment: `360*300*1*(1-(14.9/300)^0.286)` is actually 62238.70043, so your excel calculation is wrong and C is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks! I was getting a bit worried, as the calculation has to pretty precise.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I was watching a video :P Here you go.

Comment: Excel gives 62238.700433921 as the result of this formula =360*300*1*(1-(14.9/300)^0.286)  so when you get 62205 the values in R9, R10 and R11 must not be exactly the numbers you quoted - try expanding the decimals after the point displayed by excel to see what the values really are